# can't crop image with built in Windows 10 photos app without getting an "Oops! We couldn't save that one."

Tags: windows-10, photos, crop, windows-photo-viewer

I open a photo in the Windows 10 Photos app and then select the Edit option:

[image]

I then crop the image but when I try to save the cropped image I get the following error:

[image]

The error would make sense if my HDD was full but it isn't (I have 400GB+ available).

Any ideas?

Comment: In Windows Settings, Apps, go to Microsoft Photos, Advanced Options:   Repair and Reset it.  Close out and restart the computer and test.   Uninstalling Photos requires a Powershell command to uninstall, install. Use the Repair method first.

Comment: Or try a free third-party tool, such as IrfanView, with greater capapbilities.

Comment: Did you tried those suggestion on network? such as Fix: ‘Oops! We Coudn’t Save that one’ Error in Photos App https://appuals.com/fix-oops-we-coudnt-save-that-one-error-in-photos-app/